# Woocommerce and Wordpress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

WordPress and woocommerce experts.

I am designing a plugin with WordPress, but this plugin will need Woocommerce plugin as well, so I need to have woocommerce in my plugin and when I activate my plugin then Woocommerce is installed as well.

Thanks!

Comment: So what is your question? And what did you try so far to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Good way - create conditions in your plugin.

If Woocommerce plugin installed and activated - you include all your functions and your plugin will work fine.

if woocommerce not installed or not activated - you do not include all functions and create Admin Notice with text like "Woocommerce not activated. For plugin working be sure that Woocommerce Plugin installed and activated".

Something like this - good practice.

Comment: This is getting so much fun and better, i have manage to sort it and i appreciate all of your for your time to have a look at my question.